# Orthogonal matrix times low-rank-approximation proof

Tags: matrices, approximation, svd, orthogonal-matrices

I am trying to prove that a low-rank approximation of a matrix is not affected by left-multiplication by an orthogonal matrix. However, I am having problems with proving the following theorem:

Given $Q\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ matrix with orthogonal columns and $W\in M_{n\times r}(\mathbb{R})$ matrix of full rank, where $r\leq n\leq m$, show that: $$[QW]_k=Q[W]_k$$

In the given theorem, $[A]_k$ means the low-rank approximation of $A$ with rank $k$. Meaning, for $A=U\Sigma V^T$ and $u_i,v_i$ the columns of $U,V$, we get: $$[A]_k=\sum_{i=1}^k\sigma_iu_iv_i^T$$

How can I prove this theorem? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It would help to define the notation $[A]_k$ for a matrix $A$.  From the given context I understand it has something to do with "low rank approximation," but we are not told how this approximation is constructed or characterized (or what relation $k$ bears to the other parameters)